# How to write a mathematical function from a given graph?

Tags: functions

[image]

Write the mathematical function of the graph drawn in the interval [0, 2π].

Comment: What have you tried? And do you have anything other than the graph?

Comment: @Plague : Are you trying for a numerical solution?

Answer (score 1):

Step by step

It seems to be a periodic function with $T=2\pi$ (as a period)
second thing: it seems to be like $f(x)=a+b\sin x +c\sin (3x)+d\sin(5x)+\cdots$  With respect to $(0,0) \to a=0$
with respect to the graph it seems $d,e,...=0  $ because of the sine wave between the main $\sin(x)$ meet $3$ times maximum and $3$times minimum .
know you can think about $b,c$
If you put $b=1,c=\frac12$ this graph almost happens.
The second method is to get some points coordinated from the graph and put them in table to find a function that fits the first graph.
The third method is looking at Fourier Series on $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & 0\leq  x <\pi\\-1 & \pi<x<2\pi\end{cases}$$

[image]
Remark: you can take a look to this applet of Geogebra to find out what happens.  https://www.geogebra.org/m/eRJ6ygyF

Comment: Also this applet may helps you:https://www.geogebra.org/m/wUanseCs